# res.send() sending null object

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am trying to send back a person object with res.send() from the express backend to the angular frontend but res.send() is always sending a null object. I am sending data from express backend at localhost/8081 to angular frontend at localhost/4200 with cors.

**express backend**

controller.js

```
controller.getPerson = async (req, res) => {
   try{
      console.log(req.body);
      var result = await service.getPerson(req.body._id));
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result); <--- sending undefined object or nothing at all instead of result
   } 
   catch(error)
   {
        console.log("controller/get_person)", error)
   }
};
```

service.js

```
service.getPerson = (data) =>{;
       return Person.findById({'_id':data}, function(err, docs){
        console.log(docs);
            return docs;
      });
    };
```

output

```
{ _id: '5f126357aea7624680d07ee2' } <-- console.log(req.body)
console.log(docs)
{
  _id: 5f126357aea7624680d07ee2,
  first_name: 'qwer',
  last_name: 'qwer',
  __v: 0
}
console.log(result)
{
  _id: 5f126357aea7624680d07ee2,
  first_name: 'qwer',
  last_name: 'qwer',
  __v: 0
}
```

The console.log(req.body) returns {_id: 'someid'} and the console.log(docs) returns the entire person object found with the id and console.log(result) displays the same thing as console.log(docs)

**angular frontend**

person-detail.component

```
  @Input() person: Person;
  getPerson(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.personService.getPerson(id)
    .subscribe(person => this.person = person); <-- this.person is not set because person is undefined or doesn't exist
  }
```

person.service

```
  public getPerson(_id){
        return this.http.post<Person>('http://localhost:8081/get_person', {_id});
  }
```

Angular front end errors

```
core.js:4081 ERROR Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [NgControl]
at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3819)
at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:13733)
at NodeInjectorFactory.NgControlStatus_Factory [as factory] (forms.js:677)
at getNodeInjectable (core.js:3913)
at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:7973)
at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:7356)
at Module.ɵɵelementStart (core.js:13882)
at PersonDetailComponent_div_0_Template (person-detail.component.html:6)
at executeTemplate (core.js:7329)
at renderView (core.js:7138)
```

personService.getPerson(id) isn't getting the person object so person is always a null object. How can I fix it so that person => this.person = person makes this.person the person object that was sent back with res.send()?

Comment: The front and back look correct to me. if `console.log(result)` return the correct object, maybe an other part of express is interfering somehow  (e.g. an other route)?

Comment: how can I check the result at frontend? I tried console.log() in subcribe but it isn't displaying anything

Comment: @Snake comment out `.subscribe(...)` line for now. And just check these two things `const person = await this.personService.getPerson(id);` and on the next line `console.log(person)`. Also since u'll be using `await` keyword, function should be accomapnied by `async` keyword. `async getPerson()`.

Comment: I did that but console.log(person) is still not displaying anything

Comment: can I not receive data from res.send() because you can only send data with post request and not receive any data?

Comment: It does not have any impact. The HTTP methods are mostly here to specify an action to the request. You can do the same thing with post, get, put, etc. 
You can send a get request with a body if you want (even if it is maybe not the right approach).

Answer (score 1):

You're not waiting for the callback function in your service function.

Wrap it inside a promise or use the corresponding promise for `findById`.

```
service.getPerson = (data) => {
       return new Promise(resolve => { 
           Person.findById({'_id':data}, function(err, docs){
             console.log(docs);
             resolve(docs);
           });
       });
};
```

**Edit** there's a [built in promise support by mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

Comment: I did that but res.send() is still not sending result to the frontend.

Comment: I do not think it is needed. `Person.findById(...)` might already return a promise

Comment: @Jeiraon you're right. There's a built in promise by calling `.exec`. See the documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html. @Snake: what is the logged output on the controller level?

Comment: @tpschmidt I added the output for the service and controller

Comment: At least the logged output is the expected one, right? You should probably also use `res.json(result)` instead of `res.send(result)`.

Comment: yes it is expected, res.json(result) sends a undefined object too.